# Opera mini Compatibility issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, opera, opera-mini

I'm developer from India.  We have build site and which is not compatible on Opera Mini and working fine in Opera. I have found few sites which are working fine in mini same as web (infact both are same.) For eg: https://www.freecharge.in/mobile/recharge/prepaid, https://paytm.com/ etc... keyup event also working which is not available in Mini. Please help me to load site same as opera without disabling Data savings mode

---

Here is code snippet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no"/>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#E3714D">


</head>

<body>
    <form action="h" method="POST" class="card recharge-form recharge-card" name="recharge_form">
        <div class="" style="display:block;" id="rechargeBlock">
            <div class="card-wrap">
                <div class="element-container main-input no-border">
          <label for="">Mobile Number</label>
          <div class="border">
            <span class="icon phone"></span>
            <input data-required="true" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Mobile Number" maxlength="10" type="tel" name="serviceNumber" id="serviceNumber" value="" class="">
          </div>
                    <div class="error-block"></div>
                </div>




</div></form>
</body>

</html>
```

Numeric pad is not loading in opera mini

Comment: Please define your specific programming-related problem as your question is currently too broad and not well defined for anyone to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For eg: When we tap on mobile number field   in http://www.upendersanga.com/test/recharge/prepaid.html it's showing alpha numeric pad instead of numeric pad. When we check https://www.freecharge.in/mobile/recharge/prepaid  it's showing fine both are same code. I read keyup is not supported format in mini but keyup is working with freecharge

Comment: What you are describing is not a programming problem. You best need to provide an actual code sample - or reformulate your question to be much more specific. Also, please do not post links to external websites that people are supposed to click on. If you can not define your problem in code, this probably isn't the right place to ask.

Comment: Added code as answer. Please review

Comment: Please don't add answers (that are not answers...), this is not a forum, instead use the `edit` button on top to change your original question. Also, a code snippet alone doesn't generate a problem - try to tell people what your expected behaviour is with this code and what it is (or isn't) doing instead.

Comment: I'm sorry for that. I have mentioned my problem many times in post. Isn't not understandable to you? I have queried what exactly the behavior I needed

Answer (score 0):

At the moment Opera Mini in Extreme mode does not support new HTML5 input types, they fall back to standard text input. It works for you on freecharge.in, because it is silently loaded in High mode, which under the hood uses internal Android's WebView.

I recommend you spend few minutes to understand how Opera Mini works. In short: all pages are rendered on our servers and then it is transformed to very simplified format and sent to Opera Mini client. Keyup events and similar are not supported, as that would require connecting to Opera Mini servers on each key stroke. Just imagine how much time and data would it take!

I recommend to take a look at the following sites:

- https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-and-javascript/
- https://dev.opera.com/articles/making-sites-work-opera-mini/